# How to exclude non-capturing parts in the output of regexp()

Tags: regex, matlab

I have character vectors of the following format;

```
example='S(1).a=''A''; S(1).b=''B''; S(1).c=''C''; S(1).d=''D''; \n'
```

And I want to extract the parts before every `;`. (Ultimately, I want to `eval()` the whole text.)

So I tried

```matlab
expression='(?:.*?);\s?';
result=regexp(example,expression,'match');
```

The matches are correct for the given example. However, they include the non-capturing parts from `';\s?'` outside `()`.

And when I tried different [Outkeys](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html?s_tid=doc_ta#btn_p45_sep_shared-outkey) such as `'tokens'` and `'names'`, there is no result -- probably because I didn't enter token names.

How do I only capture the parts in the group `(?:.*?)`?

The other thing is .. a confirmation that my expression does correctly extract parts matching the pattern *of minimal length* would be great. If not, please advise how to do it correctly. I am new to `regexp()`. Thanks.

Comment: *"How do I only capture the parts in `()`..."* can read a bit confusing, because it could also mean to match what's inside parentheses. *"However, they include the non-capturing parts..."* you don't "capture" anything in your current pattern. `(?:` opens a [non capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap).

Answer (score 1):

You might use a negated character class, and start the match with a non whitespace character other than a semicolon, asserting a semicolon to the right.

You can omit the optional `\s?` from the pattern as it is optional and would alway match in the assertion.

```
[^\s;][^;]*(?=;)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dSGmy9/1)

Or use a capture group `()` to get what you want, and matching the trailing semicolon:

```
([^\s;][^;]*);
```

[Regec demo](https://regex101.com/r/0LRuVi/1)